# Where is git repository of Xcode stored? And Why different repository is created when I copy project directory?

Tags: iphone, xcode, git

I'm using built-in git of Xcode.

I think my project directory is just a working copy of repository.

How can I know where repository is stored?

And when I copied a project directory, a new different repository is automatically created for new project directory instead of sharing the repository of old project directory.
That is convenient but why that happend?

Comment: please comment the reasons if you downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but that's just how git works and a quick Google search would tell you that. The full history is stored within your project's `.git` folder.

Comment: the .git folder is hidden, that's why you can't see it. Turn hidden files visible.

Comment: Or use Terminal.app with `ls -al` to see a full listing of your project directory including the `.git` directory.

Comment: thanks. i thought git uses both repository and working copy like SVN. I knew that .git file exists in project folder and aslo knew how to see . file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Git stores the repository in the top-most `.git` folder of your working directory. So, if your code is in `/Users/js/Code/MyProject`, then the repository is in `/Users/js/Code/MyProject/.git/`.

Git encourages every repository to contain a single "project". Although it's *possible* to store unrelated branches that don't share any history in a single repository, that is very nonstandard and might be confusing to other people.

It's also *possible*, but discouraged, to store unrelated projects as subdirectories within a single working directory. This would make it difficult to see the history of each individual project, since you'd have to inspect each individual commit to figure out which project it affected, and merges would be downright **painful**.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I was a SVN user. I'll learn about git.